# Output Python Dictionary 'Values' as binary format

Tags: python, dictionary

I have trying to solve this issue for a while. Have looked for simple answer but to no avail. Any help much appreciated. I have created a python dictionary and am trying to format the output of the values only as binary data. In other words for each string value in the dictionary I want to output its binary value. My code and the error I am getting are below.

```
pigpen = {}
pigpen['a'] = 'ETL'
pigpen['b'] = 'ETM'
pigpen['c'] = 'ETR'
pigpen['d'] = 'EML'
pigpen['e'] = 'EMM'
pigpen['f'] = 'EMR'
pigpen['g'] = 'EBL'
pigpen['h'] = 'EBM'
pigpen['i'] = 'EBR'
pigpen['j'] = 'DTL'
pigpen['k'] = 'DTM'
pigpen['l'] = 'DTR'
pigpen['m'] = 'DML'
pigpen['n'] = 'DMM'
pigpen['o'] = 'DMR'
pigpen['p'] = 'DBL'
pigpen['q'] = 'DBM'
pigpen['r'] = 'DBR'
pigpen['s'] = 'EXT'
pigpen['t'] = 'EXL'
pigpen['u'] = 'EXR'
pigpen['v'] = 'EXB'
pigpen['w'] = 'DXT'
pigpen['x'] = 'DXL'
pigpen['y'] = 'DXR'
pigpen['z'] = 'DXB'

import binascii
str = pigpen.values()
print ' '.join(format(ord(string), 'b') for string in str)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pigpen_build.py", line 62, in <module>
    print ' '.join(format(ord(string), 'b') for string in str)
  File "pigpen_build.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    print ' '.join(format(ord(string), 'b') for string in str)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found
>>>
```

Comment: What do you mean by binary value? can you provide an example output please?

Comment: Binary value is the ascii value of the character. Look at python's `ord` and `chr` functions for this.

Comment: Many thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

@Preston beat me to it with a better answer, but here is a solution that does not use nested list comprehension.

```
binary_translation = []
for string in a:
    for char in string:
        binary_translation.append(''.join(format(ord(char), 'b')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking `ord` to find a value based on 3 characters in a string. More on [the ord function here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) In your for loop you are interacting over a list so your code expanded is like this.

```
for s in ['ABC','CDE','FGH']:
  print s+', ',
```

Which would output, `ABC, CDE, FGH`. To fix this either put another for loop on the actual string, or combine your original list into one string.

1) Another for loop.

```
print ' '.join(format(ord(string), 'b') for string in (''.join(s for s in str)))
```

2) Actual string.

```
str = ''.join(s for s in str)
print ' '.join(format(ord(stirng), 'b') for string in str)
```